# queue function for Multiprocess Priority Queue in python with SyncManager class

Tags: python, multiprocessing, priority-queue

I wanted to implement multiprocessing priorityqueue .
I found this answer :- [Strange Queue.PriorityQueue behaviour with multiprocessing in Python 2.7.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324560/strange-queue-priorityqueue-behaviour-with-multiprocessing-in-python-2-7-6)

by [Dano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073595/dano)

After I implemented this . I could use .get() and .put() function for my Priority Queue but when i used .queue to print the current elements in the queue it gave me an error

code:-

```
 class MyManager(SyncManager):   
    pass

def get_manager():
    MyManager.register("PriorityQueue", PriorityQueue)  # Register a shared PriorityQueue
    m = MyManager()
    m.start()
    return m

m = get_manager()
call= m.PriorityQueue()
for i in range(5):
    call.put(i)

print(call.queue)
```

Error : `AttributeError: 'AutoProxy[PriorityQueue]' object has no attribute 'queue'`

I read the python documentation for SyncManager and modified my code .

New code :-

```
class MyManager(SyncManager):   
    pass

def get_manager():
    MyManager.register("PriorityQueue", PriorityQueue,exposed=['put','get','queue'])  # Register a shared PriorityQueue
    m = MyManager()
    m.start()
    return m

m = get_manager()
call= m.PriorityQueue()
for i in range(5):
    call.put(i)

print(call.queue)
```

Now output was :-

```
<bound method AutoProxy[PriorityQueue].queue of <AutoProxy[PriorityQueue] object, typeid 'PriorityQueue' at 0x7ff3b48f2dd0>>
```

I am still not getting the elements in the queue , i read about `method_to_typeid` attribute of register function to map the return type of functions mentioned in `exposed`  , but i don't know how use that .

Can someone help me with this , so that i could print elements of the queue without poping them from queue

Comment: `queue` seems to be a method, so you need to call it. Try `call.queue()` (which might give you another error if it requires any arguments).

Comment: `queue`  is not callable . so we don't need parenthesis () with `queue` , whether a normal Queue ,multiprocessing Queue or any other kind of Queue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use **methods** of a referent through a proxy. Since `PriorityQueue().queue` is not a method, but an instance attribute, you need to provide a method which can return the value of this attribute.
The example below opts for a generalized `get_attribute` method with subclassing `PriorityQueue`.

```
# Python 3.7.1
from queue import PriorityQueue
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
from multiprocessing import Process


SENTINEL = None


class MyPriorityQueue(PriorityQueue):
    def get_attribute(self, name):
        return getattr(self, name)


class MyManager(SyncManager):
    pass


def get_manager():
    MyManager.register("PriorityQueue", MyPriorityQueue)
    m = MyManager()
    m.start()
    return m


def f(q):
    for item in iter(lambda: q.get()[1], SENTINEL):
        print(item)
    print(f'queue: {q.get_attribute("queue")}')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    m = get_manager()
    pq = m.PriorityQueue()

    tasks = enumerate([f'item_{i}' for i in range(5)] + [SENTINEL])

    for task in tasks:
        pq.put(task)

    print(f'queue: {pq.get_attribute("queue")}')
    print(f'maxsize: {pq.get_attribute("maxsize")}')

    p = Process(target=f, args=(pq,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Example Output:

```
queue: [(0, 'item_0'), (1, 'item_1'), (2, 'item_2'), (3, 'item_3'), (4, 'item_4'), (5, None)]
maxsize: 0
item_0
item_1
item_2
item_3
item_4
queue: []
```

Comment: thanks , worked perfectly and cleared my doubts also .