# How to extract multiprocessing queue elements without removing

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, autoproxy

I'm not able to extract a multiprocessing queue's elements due to AutoProxy error.

Normal way extracting queue's elements without removing is to do - list(q.queue) where q-> queue object.
Doesn't seem to work for MP queue.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

q = mp.Manager().Queue(maxsize=20)

list(q)
```

```
TypeError: 'AutoProxy[Queue]' object is not iterable
```

```
list(q.queue)
```

```
AttributeError: 'AutoProxy[Queue]' object has no attribute 'queue'
```

```
list(q.queue.queue)
```

```
AttributeError: 'AutoProxy[Queue]' object has no attribute 'queue'
```

The same happens when I use:

```
q = mp.Queue(maxsize=20)
```

I want to be able to extract queue elements without doing a q.get() and want to continue to use a shared queue as it's used by multiple processes.

Comment: You try to synchronize your threads with https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

Comment: I'm using multiprocessing n not multithreading.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the manager's Queue? As a proxy it is pointing to a shared queue, It won't accept objects as pool methods.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't use a shared list right away? Yes, it needs explicit locking, but queues simply don't support your requirement from a design point of view.

Comment: Whether I use manager's queue or just multiprocessing queue, I'm still not able to extract queue contents. I just need the information in the queue elements.

Comment: I want to process requests coming in, in a FIFO basis. I ended up using queue for that, I also used locks wherever necessary, n everything worked fine until I wanted to list the queue contents.

Comment: You can only access a `multiprocessing.Queue` through its published interface, full stop—so you're going to have to use `get()` method.

Comment: Another way is to do : new_q= q and do a new_q.get() instead of q.get() . This way, original 'q' contents are unaltered.

Comment: @RojaPatil No. `new_q = q` just adds another name to the Queue object (resp. proxy object)  referenced by `q` in your namespace. `new_q.get()` _will_ alter that one underlying object both names refer to.

Comment: So, how do I copy without referencing it? Is there a way?

Comment: `Manager.Queue` is actually a `queue.Queue` (multithreading-queue, but on a separate server-process) under the hood, not a `multiprocessing.Queue`.
Proxy-objects only expose methods, not attributes. You need to subclass `queue.Queue` and expand it with a method returning the attribute, then register this new Queue-class with the manager.
You can adapt my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53623278/9059420) for your use case (switch `queue.PriorityQueue` for `queue.Queue`).

Comment: As a workaround, possibly lock the queue, retrieve all items one by one, and then put them all back in.  Super inefficient but may work for you for now while you consider @Darkonaut solution above.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Darkonaut . I simplified the solution to fit my needs.You are a life saver.

Thank you all for your help and support.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 , I had that in my mind initially, but as u say, it's inefficient.
I also thought of disguising 'q' as a normal Queue inside a shared MP list, in which case, the q would always be referred as the first element of the list. This way, I can access all the attributes and still have the 'q' shared across.

Answer (score -1):

for multiprocessing's Queue..

```
q = Queue()
q.put(2)
q.put(4)

elements = list()
while q.qsize():
    elements.append(q.get())
print(elements)
```

Comment: What if I just want to read the top element of the queue instead of popping it out by q.get()?

Comment: A q.get() essentially removes the top most element, which I do not want, I want to be able to read the Queue elements w/o modifying the Queue.
@Darkonaut's solution at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53613583/queue-function-for-multiprocess-priority-queue-in-python-with-syncmanager-class/53623278#53623278 does wonders